# Find the Probability mass function of $X$

Tags: probability, functions, probability-distributions

We select $4$ random digits where in each turn I have $10$ possible output: ${0,1,2,3,...,9}$

let $X$ be the maximum digit that we got, Find the Probability mass function of $X$.

---

I know that the possibly of getting specific debit is $1/10$ thus the possibility of specific vector of for is $(1/10)^4$ plus:

$P(X=0)=P(0000)=(1/10)^4$

$P(X=1)=1-P(X not = 1)=1-((X=0)+(X=2)+(X=3)+...+(X=9))$

Any suggestions on how to solve this one?

Comment: any help with this one?

Answer (score 1):

Let the four numbers that you get be $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$ and $X_4$. Now
\begin{align}
\Pr\{\max(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)\leq x\}&=\Pr\{X_1\leq x,X_2\leq x,X_3\leq x,X_4\leq x\}\\
&=\Pr\{X_1\leq x\}\Pr\{X_2\leq x\}\Pr\{X_3\leq x\}\Pr\{X_4\leq x\}
\end{align}
where the second equality results from independence. Now you should find $\Pr\{X_i\leq x\}$ and continue; recall the $X_i$'s have the same law.

Comment: Any hint on how to calculate Xi?

Comment: The hard part is that X is a maximum which means some is equal to it for sure

Comment: @your solution doesn't work

Comment: Could you please explain why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: First equality is wrong, if I am asking for the max to be less or equal to x that doesn't mean only that each one is equal or smaller to x but also means one of them is x

Comment: but you do not know which is the max, right? so, any can be the max.